# How to permanently change niceness of apache2 process on a Debian server?

Tags: debian, apache2, nice, process-priority

I have Debian 11.2 with Apache2. I'd like to change niceness of all of my apache2 processes, or at least mod_wsgi processes, to +5. How can I do it?

Adding `Nice=5` to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service` didn't change anything, probably because that only calls `apachectl`. `renice` seems to work, but only as a temporary measure.

Comment: it would be a better solution for your to tell us your business related question or issue instead of editing `/etc/security/limits.conf` or any random file for your specific situation

Comment: I'm not sure if that answers your concerns, but my overall goal is for my Apache2 server running Django on mod_wsgi to not slow down other, more important applications on my server, such as ssh server or mail server, even when under a large load. Hence, I want the scheduler to de-prioritize Apache2. I don't understand how `/etc/security/limits.conf` would help with that.

Comment: you should consider o. not to create a single point of failure by hosting every thing in one server. In cases like where you are at such loads, i would suggest to split

Comment: This and introducing optimizations is a good long-term goal towards which I might go as the application develops, but the short-term solution I need is lowering the priority of apache2 process in scheduler that persists across restarts of apache2.

Comment: i already added the file name where you can adjust it, maybe it's a vit hidden for you ;)